# Add featured image section in article (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I just installed wordpress and my post article section did not come with "featured image". Is there a way to enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply add `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` in function.php